# Using a regex or other mechanism to find tags in a NSAttributedString (or NSString)

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have an NSAttributedString like so:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"EThis string shows my #tags. Click on a #tag now."];
```

What do I use to find the location and end of all tags? Is there a good regex for this or another better way in iOS?

Note: My definition of a tag starts with # and ends with the last alphanumeric character is hit. So a period (.), space, or dash would end the tag.

Thanks.

Comment: What about `(#.*?)[. -]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you need is `NSRegularExpression` and the particular method that will give you the start and length of each match is [`matchesInString:options:range`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/matchesInString:options:range:).

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
#.*?[A-Za-z0-9](?=[.\\s-])
```

or

```
#.*?[A-Za-z0-9](?=[. -])
```

The above regex would match all the strings which starts with `#` then matches upto the first alphanumeric character which is immediately followed by a space or dot or dash.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yU1aN2/2)

Comment: My delimiter is anything that is not numeric. Can I get the start and length of each tag too?

Comment: `My delimiter is anything that is not numeric` , i don't know what you mean by this..

Comment: Did you  mean numeric or alphanumeric? then this `#[A-Za-z0-9]+` will do the job.

Comment: How do I get the start and lengtht of the string in objective-c tho?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the string then you can use `NSScanner` class like that below:-

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mtStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"EThis string shows my #tags. Click on a #tag now."];
NSString *string = mtStr.string;
// Set up convenience variables for the start and end tag;
NSString *startTag = @"#";
NSString *endTag = @".";
NSString *title;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
[scanner scanUpToString:startTag intoString:nil];
[scanner scanString:startTag intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:endTag intoString:&title];
NSLog(@"Value is: %@", title);
```